# What is JAXBContext.newInstance(String contextPath)?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I see the usage of the below method in my project

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.test.customer");
```

where `org.test.customer` is the package name.

Does it mean we can marshal/unmarshal classes which lies under `org.test.customer`?

My understanding is based on 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)

Comment: If you read further on the page, I think it should be giving you enough information: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explanation is in `JAXBContext` class`s Javadoc

The `JAXBContext` instance is initialized from a list of colon separated Java package names. Each java package contains JAXB mapped classes, schema-derived classes and/or user annotated classes.

Example:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" );
```

Comment: So my understanding that  we can marshal/unmarshal classes which lies only under org.test.customer is correct ?

Comment: Basically yes, though you can specify classes from other packages using @XmlSeeAlso

Comment: Thanks!! I needed to know that more than one package can be included as a colon separated list.

Comment: I have one small doubt with regards to `JAXB new instance`. I need to `unmarshal` the classes which are present in the different `maven submodule`. I know now how to pass the `package` name when in the same `maven module or project` but if the classes are present in different `submodules` then how can I pass the `package` name? Do I need to pass the `package` name along with the `submodule` information? if so then can you provide me an example? I tried a. lot of things and searched many answers but could not find anything.